# Convert and redirect URL in uppercase to lowercase using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect a URL with uppercase characters `http://localhost/A/B` to a lowercase version `http://localhost/a/b` using the `.htaccess` file.

Using regex I can capture A and B but is it possible to convert them to lowercase?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
```

Tested, works, if you have the mod_speling enabled.

Or, in a serverwide httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

From: http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: he **specifically** said using .htaccess ! you should had read the comments before even copying the link.

Comment: Indeed, well spotted. My answer will cause a server error in an .htaccess file. :o

Comment: oops! I was about to jump in joy looking at Grizly's reply :-(

Comment: Added a working .htaccess version.. ;-) Of course, if you don't have access to httpd.conf, you probably won't have access to load the speling module.. will only lowercase if the folder/file is in lowercase on filesystem.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Apache 2.4 then in `.htaccess` you can use mod_rewrite with an *Apache expression* in a `RewriteCond` directive to make use of the `tolower()` function. (You no longer need access to the server config to create a rewrite map.)

For example, the following will need to go near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects/corrects any URL containing uppercase letters to the same - all lowercase - URL.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `[A-Z]` simply checks there is at least one uppercase letter in the requested URL-path. The `RewriteCond` directive then calls the `tolower()` function on the URL-path (`REQUEST_URI` server variable) the result of which is then effectively *captured* using the regex `/(.*)/`.

The `%1` backreference in the *substitution string* then holds the result of the `tolower()` function call (as stored by the capturing group in the preceding condition), ie. the lowercase'd URL-path. Notably, this includes the slash prefix.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can making testing problematic.

Comment: cool! In my use case I wanted to only lowercase directory names, not files. Adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s` prevents filenames being lowercased.

Comment: Pretty cool, but I can't wrap my head around *why* it works, I mean why `tolower(%{REQUEST_URI})` value is stored in the `RewriteCond` capture group `=~ /(.*)/`?
Shouldn't something like this be more correct? `(tolower(%{REQUEST_URI})) =~ /.*/` where the capture group is around `tolower()`?

Comment: @Gruber Capturing groups (and the corresponding _backreferences_) are a regex construct. The regex (RHS) matches against the _result_ (string) of the expression (LHS) and is used to capture/validate elements of the _result_ (the same principle in most languages when you apply a regex to a string). In this case we simply want to capture the entire result, so use the all encompassing `(.*)`. However, you could, for instance, use the regex `^\/([a-z]{2})` if you needed to only capture the first two lowercased letters (and excluding URLs that start with non-letters).

Comment: @Gruber Without the Apache Expression (expr), that is used to call the `tolower()` function, you could already do something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)` - this simply captures the entire value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the `%1` backreference that can be used in later _conditions_ and the `RewriteRule` _substitution_. (Although that particular use case would be rather pointless as you could just use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable directly instead.)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You should reference where you got your solution from: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/

Comment: It's not working. Did you test it before posting Answer?

Comment: This won't work as written if you are wanting to convert virtual URL paths that contain additional pathname information (path-info). You will need the `DPI` flag (Apache 2.2.12+) on each of the internal rewrites in order to discard the path-info and prevent it being re-appended to the rewritten URL.