# Rewrite URL to CAPITALIZE one word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

In an attempt to preempt all of the comments I'm surely going to get telling me that this is a terrible idea and that it's bad for SEO... I fully understand the repercussions of what I'm asking. However, due to the nature of the project I'm working on, it's something the client specifically requires. I'm working on a multi-site WordPress install for a network of blogs related to D/s for a client, and in that type of dynamic, the Dominant's title is always capitalized, while the submissive's title is lowercase.

So for instance, they want the following:
https://example.com/Sir - sub-site of primary example.com network install
and
https://example.com/babygirl - sub-site of primary example.com network install

I've been attempting to reverse engineer some of the [answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess) I've seen regarding forcing lowercase URLs with .htaccess or even the vhosts file in apache. But I can't seem to figure out how to only capitalize that one word "Sir" in the URL, rather than converting everything after the domain name to all caps.

This is a clean install, with literally no content yet, so if I can get this working, they shouldn't have to worry about any duplicate content issues with search engines (right?). At any rate, any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if you only point me in the right direction, because I feel like I'm chasing my tail trying to find the answer.

Comment: Presumably you are already linking to the correctly cased URL? (A `rel="canonical"` tag would resolve any duplicate content issues.) So, this is only for when a user _types_ the wrongly cased URL? "...related to D/s for a client, and in that type of dynamic, the Dominant's title is always capitalized, while the submissive's title is lowercase." - sorry, not sure what you mean? How do you know which words should be be capitalised and which should not? And where do these words appear? Always the first path segment?

Comment: If the solution from the linked answer is working for you, in that it's capitalising the whole word (but the correct words) then it should be relatively trivial to modify this to only capitalise the first letter. Please edit your question to include the code you are working with, that perhaps capitalises the whole word.

Comment: This is something you should do in a WordPress plugin, not in a .htaccess. Even if you rewrite it in Apache, WordPress would just change it back, unless you write code to do otherwise. Our sister site [wordpress.se] can help you with this.

Comment: I actually figured this out on my own and it was a lot simpler than I was trying to make it. Thank you for the comments. All I needed to do was capitalize the word in the "Siteurl" and "Home" option fields from the network admin panel for the sub-site I wanted capitalized. Moderators, feel free to close this question if you'd like. I doubt many other people will be searching for this particular issue, so it's not likely to add much value to the site.