# apache (httpd) - How to set rewrite URL

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http, rewrite, httpd

I have a new website on Nette Framework, the problem is that the **old website** had URLs in the form:

```
https://example.com/Questions/
https://example.com/Tags
```

So all over the internet there are **backlinks to the above URL** formats.

The problem is that the **new site displays 404** on those pages because the correct addresses are:

```
https://example.com/questions/
https://example.com/tags
```

So I need to somehow overwrite `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL from the wrong form of addresses to the correct form, so automatically rewrite the following in the URL:

```
A -> a
B -> b
...
Z -> z
```

Is it going through `.htaccess` somehow please?

Note that the **404 is generated by the Nette Framework** itself, so something like:

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

It will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert and redirect URL in uppercase to lowercase using .htaccess](https://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess) - assuming you just need to convert the URL to lowercase?

Comment: Specifically, see [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1043764/49157) in the [linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess) that uses an Apache _expression_ (Apache 2.4) in a mod_rewrite/`RewriteCond` directive in `.htaccess` to convert/redirect a URL to all lowercase.

Comment: @MrWhite working fine, thanks you. :-)